# elasticsearch more_like_this query is taking long time to run

Tags: elasticsearch, query-optimization, morelikethis

I have the below more_like_this query to elasticsearch.
I run this in a loop for 15 times with different art_title and art_tags each time. For some articles the time it takes is very less but for some articles in the loop it takes too long to execute. Is there anything which I can do to optimize this query. Any help is appreciated.

```
bodyquery={
        "query":
               {"bool":
                    {"should":
                         [
                            {"more_like_this":
                               {
                                    "like_text": art_title,
                                    "fields": ["title"],
                                    "max_query_terms": 30,
                                    "boost": 5,
                                    "min_term_freq": 1
                               }
                            },
                            {"more_like_this":
                               {
                                    "like_text": art_tags,
                                    "fields": ["tags"],
                                    "max_query_terms": 30,
                                    "boost": 5,
                                    "min_term_freq": 1
                                }
                            }
                         ]
                    }
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have solved this already by now but depending on the content of your indexed docs and the analyzers applied to the fields you are looking at, this can take a wide range of time to complete.  Think how similarity works and how it will be calculated for your documents and you probably will find the answer.  Also, you can use the explain param to get a Lucene detailed step-by-step response to the question
, but just in case I want to add: it is virtually impossible to determine anything without more details:

- What your mappings look like
- How are those fields analyzed
- What version of ES are you using
- Your ES setup

Also, describe in english what are you trying to retrieve: "I want documents in the catalog index that have a title similar to art_title and/or a tag similar to art_tag".

There is reference to the syntax in [HERE](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) if you are using the latest version of ES

Cheers